# MenuItem containerElement Links broken after upgrading to v1 material-ui

Tags: material-ui, react-router-dom

Old menu items broken with react-router-dom

```
     <MenuItem
                containerElement={<Link to="/module" />} >Module</MenuItem>
```

This stopped working....

How can I upgrade these new Menu Item controls to work with react-router?

I've tried replacing containerElement with root, and also surrounding by  tag but that leaves the hyperlink underlined. I'd like to keep the same style as MenuItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this post: [How to do routing with material-ui@next MenuItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462853/how-to-do-routing-with-material-uinext-menuitem)

see demo.js from here https://codesandbox.io/s/5213wzkvpl

You can use Link as child for MenuItem:

```
<MenuList>
  <MenuItem>
    <Link to="/myRoute" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', display: 'flex' }}>
      go to my route
    </Link>
  </MenuItem>
</MenuList>
```