# How to do routing with material-ui@next MenuItem?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

What's the best practice to implement routing using the `material-ui@next`? In the previous version I could use `containerElement` with a `Link` but doesn't work anymore. Couldn't find any help in the docs.

```
 <MenuItem containerElement={<Link to="/myRoute" />}>My Link</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Link` as parent component for `MenuItem`:

```
  <MenuList>
    <Link to="/myRoute" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', display: 'block' }}>
      <MenuItem>
        go to my route
      </MenuItem>
    </Link>
    <Link to="/anotherRoute" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', display: 'block' }}>
      <MenuItem>
        go to another route
      </MenuItem>
    </Link>
  </MenuList>
```

Comment: This only works if you click on the actual text. Any clue how to make the entire item clickable?

Comment: @BryanStump I modified the answer, check, please.

Comment: Unfortunately, the style is broken with this answer :(

Answer (score 17):

you can now give the `MenuItem` a component prop like this:

```
<MenuItem component={Link} to='/myRoute'>
go to my route
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: For React Router, the Link must be imported from `react-router-dom`, not `@mui`